# Error when performing operations with different types and assigning result to an arrray

Tags: php, arrays, types

I receive 2 values per post: **price_ex** and **price_cr**.

These values are of type string: '4.45' and '4.60'.

I want to multiply them by 100 to get the value in euro cents.

The result of this operation returns me that the variables are of type double and the values are:

```
precioExpendeduriaEnCents: 445 precioConRecargoEnCents: 460
```

However, when creating an array `$aParametros`  and assigning these values to it, when printing the array in my log file I see the following:

```
Product - edit.php - aParameters: {"id": "5074",..., "price_ex": 445, "price_cr": 459.99999999999994,...}
```

Why is the value of price_cr is 459.99999999999994?
(I expected the value 460)

I have tried to fix it by casting (float) to the 2 variables (**price_ex** and **price_cr**) and also with the `floatval` function but it has not worked

**Full code:**

```
registrarLog('Productos - Edit. $_POST: '.json_encode($_POST));

$precio_ex = $_POST["precio_ex"];   
$precio_cr = $_POST["precio_cr"];

registrarLog("Producto - edit.php | precio_ex: ".$precio_ex.' precio_cr: '.$precio_cr, DEBUG);

registrarLog("Producto - edit.php - precio_ex: ".gettype($precio_ex), DEBUG);
registrarLog("Producto - edit.php - precio_cr: ".gettype($precio_cr), DEBUG);

 $precioExpendeduriaEnCents = $precio_ex*100;
 $precioConRecargoEnCents = $precio_cr*100;


registrarLog("Producto - edit.php - precioExpendeduriaEnCents: ".gettype($precioExpendeduriaEnCents), DEBUG);
registrarLog("Producto - edit.php - precioConRecargoEnCents: ".gettype($precioConRecargoEnCents), DEBUG);
    
registrarLog("Producto - edit.php | precioExpendeduriaEnCents: ".$precioExpendeduriaEnCents.' precioConRecargoEnCents: '.$precioConRecargoEnCents, DEBUG);
        $aParametros = [
            'id' => ($id != "") ? $id : null,
            'nombre' => $nombre,
            'cod_oficial' => $cod_oficial,
            'precio_ex' => $precioExpendeduriaEnCents,
            'precio_cr' => $precioConRecargoEnCents,
            'id_fabricante' => $id_fabricante,
            'clase' => $clase,
            'imagen' => $imagen,
            'image_valid' => $image_valid,
            'fecha_modificacion' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'id_usuario' => ($_SESSION['id_perfil'] == SUPERADMINISTRADOR) ? $id_usuario = null : $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario']
        ];
        registrarLog("Producto - edit.php - aParametros: ".json_encode($aParametros), DEBUG);
```

**Full log:**

```
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Productos - Edit. $_POST: {"cod_oficial":"11111","nombre":"Superproducto","id_fabricante":"2","clase":"Cigarrillos","precio_ex":"4.45","precio_cr":"4.60","MAX_FILE_SIZE":"60000","id":"5074","parent_id":"labores","image":""}
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php | precio_ex: 4.45 precio_cr: 4.60
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php - precio_ex: string
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php - precio_cr: string
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php - precioExpendeduriaEnCents: double
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php - precioConRecargoEnCents: double
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php | precioExpendeduriaEnCents: 445 precioConRecargoEnCents: 460
15/12/2021 16:23:23 - ::1 - 94 - Jorge | Producto - edit.php - aParametros: {"id":"5074",...,"precio_ex":445,"precio_cr":459.99999999999994,...}
```

Note: I don't know if it matters but the php file is executed by a jquery call

**Edit:**

I also put the code that inserts the record with the value 459 in DB:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO m_labores (nombre, cod_oficial, cod_fam_azk, cod_prod_azk, cod_four, precio_ex, precio_cr, id_fabricante, clase, imagen, image_valid, fecha_modificacion, id_usuario)"
                ." VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$sentencia = mysqli_prepare(db_connect(), $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sentencia, 'sssssiiissisi', 
        $aParametros['nombre'], 
        $aParametros['cod_oficial'],
        $codigoFamiliaAzkoyen,
        $codigoProductoAzkoyen,
        $codigoFour,
        $aParametros['precio_ex'],
        $aParametros['precio_cr'],
        $aParametros['id_fabricante'],
        $aParametros['clase'],
        $aParametros['imagen'],
        $aParametros['image_valid'],
        $aParametros['fecha_modificacion'],
        $aParametros['id_usuario']
    );

    mysqli_stmt_execute($sentencia);

$id = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($sentencia);
    mysqli_stmt_close($sentencia);
```

Comment: Minimum code: https://www.tehplayground.com/lyhW0MLzuYNpq2hH. It's in `json_encode()`.

Comment: Okay @JMP , from your answer I understand that it is the `json_encode` function that produces this strange value.
However, I use the values of the array to make an insert in my DB and my code registers the 459 value. How is it possible? I only use json_encode to paint arrays in my log file.

Comment: Which DB do you use?

Comment: I use my Mysql DB

Comment: They both (json and mysql_query) must access the raw `$w` without it's visual typecast partner. Only PHP is displaying `4.60` for a double of actual value `4.599..`.

Comment: If you write `var_dump($w)`, you get `4.5999...`,

Comment: That is exactly what I was testing just now.
If you run `echo $a['w']` = 460 but if you run `var_dump($a['w'])` = 459.999 ...

I have tried to pass variables (**$price_ex** and **$price_cr**) instead of the array to my insert function and it works fine: It registers the value 460.

Do you know of any option that mysql_query will take the value 460 using the array?

Thanks so much for the help. It has been very useful